# Add an image over another image: Could not broadcast input array from shape

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to add an image onto another larger image, but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, and advise on how to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: First dimension is "image rows", thus `y` or `height`. I guess you just need so switch the arguments in that line, i.e. `img[193:193+..., 123:123+...]`.

Comment: Thank you! That did it.